# Image alternating function alternates wrong image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and am taking a Web Design class. I'm required to make a banner ad that alternates between two different images (`banner1.jpg` & `banner2.jpg`). The problem I'm having is when my site loads it displays `banner1.jpg` above the `<h2>`, and `court.jpg` below. Then it changes `court.jpg` to `banner2.jpg` then to `banner1.jpg`, alternating back & forth between the two banners. The `banner1.jpg` above the `<h2>` stays static. Here's the relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

var curImage="banner1";
function bannerAd() {
 if (curImage == "banner2") {
 document.images[1].src = "images/banner1.jpg";
 curImage = "banner1";
 }
 else {
 document.images[1].src = "images/banner2.jpg";
 curImage = "banner2";
 }
}

/* ]]> */
</script>    

</head>
  <body onload="var changeImages=setInterval('bannerAd()', 2000);">
    <header>
        <h1>Basketball Almanac</h1>
    </header>
<section class="main"> 
    <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="Banner image" />
    <h2>Basketball Analysis</h2>
    <p><span class="companyname">Basketball Almanac</span> is your one-stop site for in-depth basketball analysis and statistics.</p>
    <img class="main" src="images/court.jpg" alt="NBA Court" />
```

How do I make it so only `banner1.jpg` changes? Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know if it would help to include more of the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, in javascript, arrays are 0 based, so the frist object is [0]

So you want

```
var curImage="banner1";

function bannerAd() {
 if (curImage == "banner2") {
 document.images[0].src = "images/banner1.jpg";
 curImage = "banner1";
 }
 else {
 document.images[0].src = "images/banner2.jpg";
 curImage = "banner2";
 }
}
```

or to simplify it a little

```
var curImage="images/banner2.jpg";

function bannerAd() {
 if (curImage == "images/banner1.jpg") {
     curImage= "images/banner2.jpg";
 }
 else {
     curImage = "images/banner1.jpg";
 }

 document.images[0].src = curImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var curImage="images/banner2.jpg";

function bannerAd() {
 if (curImage == "images/banner1.jpg") {
     curImage= "images/banner2.jpg";
 }
 else {
     curImage = "images/banner1.jpg";
 }

 document.images[0].src = curImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var curImage="banner1";

function bannerAd(n) {
 if (curImage == "banner2") {
 document.images[n].src = "images/banner1.jpg";
 curImage = "banner1";
 }
 else {
 document.images[n].src = "images/banner2.jpg";
 curImage = "banner2";
 }
}
```

```html
//bannerAd(1)
  <body onload="var changeImages=setInterval('bannerAd(0)', 2000);">
    <header>
        <h1>Basketball Almanac</h1>
    </header>
<section class="main"> 
    <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="Banner image" />
    <h2>Basketball Analysis</h2>
    <p><span class="companyname">Basketball Almanac</span> is your one-stop site for in-depth basketball analysis and statistics.</p>
    <img class="main" src="images/court.jpg" alt="NBA Court" />
```